# Performing a “Group By” with sum function in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xslt, xslt-grouping

I want a result organized like following table:

```
**Costc 1000**          
    Product code    Quantity    Total amount

    SALESCOST       1   120.04
    LEASINGRENT     1   59.90

**Costc 2000**          
    Product code    Quantity    Total amount

    SALESCOST       1   118.94
    LEASINGCOST     1   513.34

**Costc 3000**          
    Product code    Quantity    Total amount

    LEASINGCOST     1   658.24
    LEASINGRENT     2   100.80
```

And the input-file I have look like this.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<Details>
    <Detail>
        <LineNo>1</LineNo>
    <Products>
        <ProductCode>SALESCOST</ProductCode>
        <ProductDescr>Sales amount asset:997000000000</ProductDescr>
        <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
    </Products>
    <Costc>
        <Value>2000</Value>
    </Costc>
    <TotAmount>118.94</TotAmount>
</Detail>
<Detail>
    <LineNo>2</LineNo>
    <Products>
        <ProductCode>LEASINGCOST</ProductCode>
        <ProductDescr>Leasing cost asset:997000000003</ProductDescr>
    </Products>
    <Costc>
        <Value>2000</Value>
    </Costc>
    <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
    <TotAmount>513.34</TotAmount>
</Detail>
<Detail>
    <LineNo>3</LineNo>
    <Products>
        <ProductCode>SALESCOST</ProductCode>
        <ProductDescr>Sales amount asset:997000000001</ProductDescr>
    </Products>
    <Costc>
        <Value>1000</Value>
    </Costc>
    <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
    <TotAmount>120.04</TotAmount>
</Detail>
<Detail>
    <LineNo>4</LineNo>
    <Products>
        <ProductCode>LEASINGCOST</ProductCode>
        <ProductDescr>Leasing cost asset:997000000002</ProductDescr>
    </Products>
    <Costc>
        <Value>3000</Value>
    </Costc>
    <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
    <TotAmount>658.24</TotAmount>
</Detail>
<Detail>
    <LineNo>5</LineNo>
    <Products>
        <ProductCode>LEASINGRENT</ProductCode>
        <ProductDescr>Leasing interest asset:997000000001</ProductDescr>
    </Products>
    <Costc>
        <Value>3000</Value>
    </Costc>
    <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
    <TotAmount>48.90</TotAmount>
</Detail>
<Detail>
    <LineNo>6</LineNo>
    <Products>
        <ProductCode>LEASINGRENT</ProductCode>
        <ProductDescr>Leasing interest asset:997000000002</ProductDescr>
    </Products>
    <Costc>
        <Value>3000</Value>
    </Costc>
    <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
    <TotAmount>51.90</TotAmount>
</Detail>
<Detail>
    <LineNo>7</LineNo>
    <Products>
        <ProductCode>LEASINGRENT</ProductCode>
        <ProductDescr>Leasing interest asset:997000000002</ProductDescr>
    </Products>
    <Costc>
        <Value>1000</Value>
    </Costc>
    <Quantity>1.00</Quantity>
    <TotAmount>59.90</TotAmount>
</Detail>
```

How can this be done?
Its multi-level group by and also sums and count function in this and it’s too complex for me.
Many thanks

Comment: If quantities can indeed be set at two levels, then Tim's XSLT 1.0 solution will have to be adjusted (see the result, where quanity for 2000/SALESCOST is 0), taking into account the second level (within products). Note that Lukasz sums quantities on both levels already.

Comment: I've adjusted my answer to cope with Quantity on two different levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In XSLT 1.0 you would need to use a technique called Meunchian Grouping. In this case you are grouping firstly by **Costc** elements, and then by **Products** elements.

This means you need to define two keys. Firstly to group details by **Costc**

```
<xsl:key name="costc" match="Detail" use="Costc/Value"/>
```

And then to group details by **Costc** and **Product**

```
<xsl:key name="product" match="Detail" use="concat(Costc/Value, '|', Products/ProductCode)"/>
```

(Do note the use of the pipe character in the concatenation. It is important this character does not appear in the value or the product code).

Then, to group by the **Costc** elements, you can do the following:

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="Detail[generate-id() = generate-id(key('costc', Costc/Value)[1])]">
```

This would get you the first **Detail** element for each unique **Costc** element. Then, for each such group, you would then group by the products within that group.

```
<xsl:apply-templates 
   select="../Detail
      [Costc/Value = current()/Costc/Value]
      [generate-id() 
         = generate-id(key('product', concat(Costc/Value, '|', Products/ProductCode))[1])]"  />
```

So, given the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="costc" match="Detail" use="Costc/Value"/>
   <xsl:key name="product" match="Detail" use="concat(Costc/Value, '|', Products/ProductCode)"/>

   <xsl:template match="/Details">
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Detail[generate-id() = generate-id(key('costc', Costc/Value)[1])]" mode="Cost">
         <xsl:sort select="Costc/Value" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Detail" mode="Cost">
      <h1><xsl:value-of select="Costc/Value" /></h1>
      <table>
         <tr>
            <td>Product Code</td>
            <td>Quantity</td>
            <td>Total amount</td>
         </tr>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="../Detail[Costc/Value = current()/Costc/Value][generate-id() = generate-id(key('product', concat(Costc/Value, '|', Products/ProductCode))[1])]" mode="Product" />
      </table>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="Detail" mode="Product">
         <tr>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="Products/ProductCode" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('product', concat(Costc/Value, '|', Products/ProductCode))//Quantity)" /></td>
            <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('product', concat(Costc/Value, '|', Products/ProductCode))/TotAmount)" /></td>
         </tr>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your sample XML, the following is output:

```
<h1>1000</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Product Code</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Total amount</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SALESCOST</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>120.04</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LEASINGRENT</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>59.9</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h1>2000</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Product Code</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Total amount</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>SALESCOST</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>118.94</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LEASINGCOST</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>513.34</td>
    </tr>
</table>
<h1>3000</h1>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Product Code</td>
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Total amount</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LEASINGCOST</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>658.24</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>LEASINGRENT</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>100.8</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the quick answer. It’s work perfect. I didn’t actually thought I would get an answer at all. Now I get I quick and also a good answer. So I am very happy and have a tear in my eye of gratitude.
Best regards from Sweden

Comment: @user1200589: "tear in my eye of gratitude" -- So exciting... At So users typically *accept* the best answer. I hope the tears in your eyes won't prevent you from accepting the answer? :) Hint: click on the check-mark next to the answer.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev ahhh...how SO used to be :) Gratitude, nice answers, etc. Maybe we will get back there someday!

Comment: @Jedidja: Why do we need to wait? We are all human beings and can act and express feelings in a natural way. SO is just the mechanism that connects us together.

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
    <xsl:output method="text"/>

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="*/Detail" group-by="Costc/Value" >
            <xsl:sort select="current-grouping-key()" order="ascending"/>

            <xsl:value-of select="concat('** Costc ',current-grouping-key())"/>
            <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;  Product code    Quantity    Total amount&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>

            <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="Products/ProductCode" >
                <xsl:text>   </xsl:text>            
                <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/>
                <xsl:text>   </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="number(sum(current-group()/Quantity, current-group()/Products/Quantity))" />              
                <xsl:text>   </xsl:text>
                                <xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/TotAmount)" />                
                <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>             
            </xsl:for-each-group>       

            <xsl:text>&#xD;&#xA;</xsl:text>

        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

You would have to work on adjusting formatting. This XSLT presents only algorithm.
This is my output:

```
** Costc 1000
  Product code    Quantity    Total amount
   SALESCOST   1   120.04
   LEASINGRENT   1   59.9

** Costc 2000
  Product code    Quantity    Total amount
   SALESCOST   1   118.94
   LEASINGCOST   1   513.34

** Costc 3000
  Product code    Quantity    Total amount
   LEASINGCOST   1   658.24
   LEASINGRENT   2   100.8
```